# correct placement of the phrase "with you right now"

Tags: placement

I have made up the sentences below.

(1) Do you have the money that you originally set aside for the picnic last week **with you right now**?

(2) Do you have the money **with you right now** that you originally set aside for the picnic last week?

I am not sure which one is correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence is fine. Your second is not.

There is, though, another acceptable version: “Do you have **with you right now** the money that you originally set aside for the picnic last week?” This version has the benefit of keeping the verb *have* and all its adverb-ish modifiers together continuously before the onset of its. (lengthy) complement—the noun phrase with head *money*.